# Command substitution in alias resolved in bash profile?

Tags: bash, freebsd, alias, profile, command-substitution

I want to make an alias for randomly changing my mac address

```
alias chrandmac="sudo ifconfig en0 ether $(openssl rand -hex 6 | sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g; s/.$//')"
```

but the command substitution part is already resolved when executing the profile.

```
alias chrandmac='sudo ifconfig en0 ether 83:3a:bf:fc:4e:29'
```

Any thoughts as to why this occurs?

Comment: The `$(....)` part is done when the alias is _defined_, not when it runs. Use a shell function.

Comment: @vonbrand it's done when it's defined because `$()` happens inside of double quotes. That can be avoided.

Comment: @jordanm, I've been badly bitten by aliases with arguments that seemed to work (along the lines you state). Better avoid that, use aliases _only_ with fixed text replacement.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You want to use a function instead of an alias. It can be put in your startup file just like an alias:

```
chrandmac() {
    sudo ifconfig en0 ether $(openssl rand -hex 6 | sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g; s/.$//')
}
```

In order to get it to work with an alias, you need to use single quotes to prevent the expansion of the command substitution.

```
alias chrandmac='sudo ifconfig en0 ether $(openssl rand -hex 6 | sed '\''s/\(..\)/\1:/g; s/.$//'\'')'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm curious how to make this with an alias.

Comment: @1.61803 answer updated

Comment: Great, the alias with your modifications works fine, thanks.